# How would I pause/stop audio playback when a SVG element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, audio, svg

Here is what I have to play the sound when an SVG element is clicked using onclick.

```
function playSound(soundfile) {
            var audio = new Audio(soundfile);
            audio.play();
}
```

I have been tearing out my hair, to pause/stop audio playback using the same structure as above.

Would anybody be able to help ?

If so, would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of just this one function (nothing really seems wrong about it as-is, out of context), a [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code I attached, its the pause/stop function I am trying to do. I have tried using:                                               
         function pauseSound(soundfile) {
            var audio = new Audio(soundfile);
            audio.pause();
}

Comment: add a global variable, then use variable = !variable to toggle it, and add an if statement that switches between audio.play and audio.stop

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```js
(function () {
  var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0],
      txt = document.getElementsByTagName('text')[0];
      audio = null;

  svg.addEventListener('click', handler, false);

  function handler() {
    if (!audio) {
      audio = new Audio('https://www.gnu.org/music/FreeSWSong.ogg');
      audio.play();
      txt.innerHTML = 'Stop';
    } else if (audio && audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
      txt.innerHTML = 'Stop';
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      txt.innerHTML = 'Play';
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
text {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <rect x="20" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="100" height="100" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" />
  <text x="51" y="75" fill="black">Play</text>
</svg>
```